# Column name in value how to collect col name and value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table containing columns where the value is a (specification and the value) in the column.
Example:

[image: example table values]

Instead of a name spec1 , spec*
I would like to have the actual spec name like Size as the column name and the value should be the part after the : in the string.
Also my table contains 30 spec fields so I want to do it as efficient as possible.

I think I need a split and a pivot and unpivot to get this to work. But if there is a beter solution for this I am al ears.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is the example code : in the string.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[question](
    [Name] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [articleNum] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [spec1] [varchar](16) NOT NULL,
    [spec2] [varchar](18) NOT NULL,
    [spec3] [varchar](17) NOT NULL,
    [spec4] [varchar](26) NOT NULL,
    [spec5] [varchar](26) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1], [spec2], [spec3], [spec4], [spec5]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'477665', N'size : Small', N'Height : 0.4 meter', N'width : 2.1 meter', N' details N/A : details N/A', N' details N/A : details N/A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1], [spec2], [spec3], [spec4], [spec5]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'477666', N'size : Medium', N'Height : 1 meter', N'width : 4 meter', N'shape : round', N'color : black')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1], [spec2], [spec3], [spec4], [spec5]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'777666', N'size : Large', N'Height : 1 meter', N'width : 3 meter', N'Material : stainles steel', N'color : green')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1], [spec2], [spec3], [spec4], [spec5]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'977666', N'Height : 1 meter', N'width : 4 meter', N'shape : round', N'color : black', N' details N/A : details N/A')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1], [spec2], [spec3], [spec4], [spec5]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'977666', N'size : Medium', N'Height : 1 meter', N'width : 4 meter', N'shape : round', N'color : black')
GO
```

Comment: Tag your question with the specific SQL Server version since the solution may vary by version. Also add the query you've tried to your question, even if not working.

Comment: please do not post image. Use formatted text instead. Also please show us in text how the expected result looks like

Comment: If I understand correctly, it's not possible, because some of your columns contain multiple values, so which would you chose. Regardless this is a problem best solved in your front end, not the database level. If you absolutely have to, you need to investigate using dynamic SQL.

Comment: Your schema would be simpler if you had removed the spec columns and created a second table with columns (articlenumber, ordinal, spec,, value) with a primary key on (articlenumber, ordinal) and a check (ordinal<=5) if you want to limit the options. Another option would be to have one spec column with a json array with all the values

Comment: If at all possible I would strongly urge you to fix this design. You have violated 1NF with repeating groups. If you instead had a second table for specs your design would be normalized and your query would be easy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a column in JSON format so that you can enter the necessary items in it completely freely. Like the example below

```
SELECT articleNum,
Name,
JSON_VALUE(JsonColumn, '$.spec1') AS People,
JSON_VALUE(JsonColumn, '$.spec2') AS Size
FROM question
```

your table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[question](
[Name] [varchar](5) NOT NULL,
[articleNum] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
[JsonColumn] [varchar](max) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
INSERT [dbo].[question] ([Name], [articleNum], [spec1]) VALUES (N'Stone', N'477665', N'data as json')
GO
```